# Object not exported by R base package on Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, windows, gcc, package

A repository was cloned with R scripts, including a directory with libraries, which was used initially on Windows machine:

```sh
sessionInfo()  
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)  
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)   

Matrix products: default

locale:  
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252  
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    

attached base packages: 
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  
[1] compiler_4.0.3  htmltools_0.5.0 tools_4.0.3     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.5  
[6] knitr_1.30      xfun_0.19       digest_0.6.27   rlang_0.4.8 evaluate_0.14
```

Then, several problems were faced like having a version 3 or failed execution by some packages. These issues were solved managing Debian settings and reinstalling such packages.

Finally when one of the scripts would be running, the current situation occurs:

```sh
install.packages(pkgs = 'TSdist', lib = .libPaths()[1], dependencies = T)  
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/TSdist_3.7.tar.gz'  
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 182707 bytes (178 KB)  
==================================================  
downloaded 178 KB  

* installing *source* package ‘TSdist’ ...  
** package ‘TSdist’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked  
** using staged installation  
** libs  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c EDR.c -o EDR.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c EDRnw.c -o EDRnw.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ERP.c -o ERP.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ERPnw.c -o ERPnw.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c LCSS.c -o LCSS.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c LCSSnw.c -o LCSSnw.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-fhxXXR/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c registerDynamicSymbol.c -o registerDynamicSymbol.o  
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o TSdist.so EDR.o EDRnw.o ERP.o ERPnw.o LCSS.o LCSSnw.o registerDynamicSymbol.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/nmorais/deployment/euniversal-clustering/libraries/00LOCK-TSdist/00new/TSdist/libs  
** R  
** data  
** inst  
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading  
Error: object ‘getWindowsHandle’ is not exported by 'namespace:utils'  
Execution halted  
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘TSdist’  
* removing ‘/home/nmorais/deployment/euniversal-clustering/libraries/TSdist’  

The downloaded source packages are in  
        ‘/tmp/RtmpwJbt3F/downloaded_packages’  
Warning message: In install.packages(pkgs = "TSdist", lib = .libPaths()[1], dependencies = T) :    
installation of package ‘TSdist’ had non-zero exit status
```

The pretended machine give us:

```sh
sessionInfo()  
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)  
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS  

Matrix products: default  
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0  
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0  
>
locale:  
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C  
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8  
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C  
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C  
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
attached base packages:  
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  
>
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  
[1] compiler_4.0.4 tools_4.0.4
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Odd, `utils::getWindowsHandle` was [last modified 17y ago](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blame/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/library/utils/R/windows/sysutils.R#L53), and the line exporting it in `NAMESPACE` has not changed in [at least 12y](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blame/trunk/src/library/utils/NAMESPACE#L179).

Comment: It's interesting because getWindowsHandle is a function to "get the Windows handle of a window or of the R process in MS Windows". It only seems to work on Windows computers. (I get an error when I try to run in on a mac or linux). It's not clear why the package would be trying to use that function on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you did something which would almost certainly cause problems:  you moved a library of packages from a Windows machine to an Ubuntu machine.  Those systems are way too different for that to work.

What you should do is make a record on the Windows machine of the names of all the installed packages, and then install those on Ubuntu, don't copy them.

I can't tell which of the packages you have on Ubuntu is messed up, so I'd recommend that you uninstall all contributed packages, and reinstall all of them.  It's not just `TSdist`:  it doesn't use `getWindowsHandle`.  It's some other package that `TSdist` is using.

Comment: The point is it's not so clear to install the packages, taking into account own versions. When you need to follow this condition, a good solution is getting something like Conda environment.

Comment: I don't think Conda will solve the problem of binary incompatibility.  The solution R uses isn't the only one, but it *works*.  It doesn't attempt binary compatibility, it relies on source compatibility.  As long as you reinstall packages (and they don't make use of Windows-specific features), they'll work fine on Ubuntu.